# expo app not fetching updates from publish

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

For some reason, I need to close and reopen the app multiple times and even clear my cache before my expo app updates.

After seeing this I went through the documentation for expo updates and I put this code in my `App.js` but I don't understand how can I force the expo app to update as soon as one is available

```
async componentDidMount() {
    try {
      const update = await Updates.checkForUpdateAsync();
      if (update.isAvailable) {
        await Updates.fetchUpdateAsync();
        // ... notify user of update ...
        await Updates.reloadAsync();
      }
    } catch (e) {
      // handle or log error
      console.log(`update his an error ${e}`)
    }
```

Comment: `Updates.reloadAsync` should trigger a notification or what is it supposed to do?

Comment: I would just send an alert saying that app restarting for update but I don't know if this is downloading the update or not

Comment: would the code above simply force an update in the app? What happens if the app boots up faster than it can check if there is an update avaliable?